# Eclipse Add text to first line of all files

Tags: regex, eclipse

I need to add text to first line of all my JSP's in eclipse, this is the regex I a using `\A.*` but some how it selects the first line, I just want to prepend text to the start of the file. any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Just use `\A` to match the start of file. `.*` matches any 0+ chars other than linebreak characters.

Comment: have tried that but it says, no text found

Comment: Funny. Even funnier than in NPP, where `\A` = `^`. Then use `^([\s\S]*)` and replace with `MY_NEW_TEXT$1`

Comment: That works, thanks a ton, you saved my day buddy, Kindly post this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.*` pattern matches any 0+ chars other than line break characters, so it matches the first line.

It seems that Eclipse *Find/Replace* regex feature does not match entirely zero-width patterns (e.g. `(?=,)` will not find and insert a text before commas).

A workaround is to match and capture some text with `(...)` (where `...` stand for a consuming pattern) capturing group and use `$1` in the replacement pattern to reinsert the matched text.

Use

```
\A(.*)
```

Replace with `MY_NEW_TEXT_HERE_AT_THE_START_OF_FILE$1`.

Comment: Well, it seems the `(.*)` with `\A` will also work. Just tried, and `\A(.*)` --> `MyNewText$1` works, too. I will edit the answer.